# Trying to setup https on qbittorrent web UI

Tags: server, 18.04, ssl, https, qbittorrent

So i am running qbittorrent on a Ubnutu 18.04 Server using the webui for the interaction. When I follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Linux-WebUI-setting-up-HTTPS-with-self-signed-SSL-certificates) once I get to the stage of entering the key and the certificate and click save the Web UI will no longer load and the only way I can get back on it is by deleting the .conf file ad restarting the service. Anyone know what I am doing wrong thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me.

Using a Let's Encrypt certificate requested via certbot (see [here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Linux-WebUI-setting-up-HTTPS-with-Let's-Encrypt-certificates)).

```
certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --must-staple --redirect --hsts --uir --staple-ocsp --rsa-key-size 4096 --domain subdomain.doman.com
```

And the certs are stored here:

```
root@server:/etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.doman.com# ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 20 14:10 ./
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Mar 20 14:10 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  692 Mar 20 14:10 README
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Mar 20 14:10 cert.pem -> ../../archive/subdomain.doman.com/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   54 Mar 20 14:10 chain.pem -> ../../archive/subdomain.doman.com/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   58 Mar 20 14:10 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/subdomain.doman.com/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   56 Mar 20 14:10 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/subdomain.doman.com/privkey1.pe
```

I had to copy the "cert.pem" and "privkey.pem" file to the following path (qbtuser is the user who runs the qBittorrent daemon)

```
mkdir /home/qbtuser/.config/qBittorrent/ssl
cd /home/qbtuser/.config/qBittorrent/ssl
chmod 0700 *.pem
chown qbtuser:qbtuser *.pem

root@server:/home/qbtuser/.config/qBittorrent/ssl# ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 qbtuser qbtuser 4096 Mar 20 15:52 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 qbtuser qbtuser 4096 Mar 20 16:34 ../
-rwx------ 1 qbtuser qbtuser 2321 Mar 20 15:59 cert.pem*
-rwx------ 1 qbtuser qbtuser 3268 Mar 20 15:59 privkey.pem*
```

Troubleshooting:

```
journalctl -f -u qbittorrent.service

systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart qbittorrent
```